# after update my sdk, app crash with android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed android app using android-support-v7-appcompat on Eclipse and it worked fine. Today i've updated the SDK to the latest version available. All works fine but when i launch one of my application i get this error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.loan.collector/com.loan.collector.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.ensureSubDecor(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:273)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:225)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
    at com.loan.collector.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:36)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Toolbar_theme
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.themifyContext(Toolbar.java:2007)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:195)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
    ... 27 more
```

And this is HomeActivity.java

```
package com.loan.collector;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import com.loan.collector.addapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import com.loan.collector.addapter.UserAdapter;
import com.loan.collector.utill.DatabaseHandler;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener{

Context context = this;
DatabaseHandler database = new DatabaseHandler(context);
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
public String[] tabs1 = { "SIGN IN", "SIGN UP"};
public String[] tabs2 = {"SIGN IN"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);  // hides action bar icon
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

exportDB();

ArrayList<UserAdapter> userList = database.getLoginUsers();



// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);   
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bar_bg));


// Adding Tabs

if(userList.size()==1){
for (String tab_name : tabs1) {
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
.setTabListener(this));
}

mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),2);

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}else{
for (String tab_name : tabs2) {
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
.setTabListener(this));
}
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),1);

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}


viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});

}

private void exportDB() {
try {
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

if (sd.canWrite()) {
// String currentDBPath =
// getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("SalesPlayLiteDB");
// String backupDBPath =
// Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Download";
File currentDB = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(
"CollectorDB");
File backupDB = new File(
Environment
.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
"CollectorDB_backup.db");

FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
src.close();
dst.close();
/*
* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Successful!",
* Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
*/

}
} catch (Exception e) {

/*
* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backup Failed!",
* Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
*/
e.printStackTrace();

}
}
@Override
public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab,
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab arg0,
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

activity_home.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_color"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Navigation Drawer Demo"
            android:textColor="@color/action_bar_text_color" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="1/1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@color/action_bar_text_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Please tell me how to fix this error, thanks

Comment: please add HomeActivity.java too

Comment: please add activity_home.xml file too

Comment: add both activity_home.xml and toolbar.xml.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sold it.It was a incompatible of appcompat_v7. So I replace the Android Support Library using previous version.It is Revision 21.0.2.

- download Revision 21.0.2 from http://androidtoolsofflinedownload.blogspot.com/p/download-  android-support-library-offline.html
- replace to sdk\extras\android\support
- Removing support library appcompat_v7 from workspace & re-importing it from sdk location.

Answer (score 0):

Try, Removing support library appcompat_v7 from  workspace & re-importing it from sdk location.